# variable declaration in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been doing something like this for a while and I have never seen any errors. But, unfortunately, I have never been able to explain why this works.

The first line creates a variable which points to a function. The second line just adds `func2` to `func1` separated by a dot and defines a function.

If I add a `var` in front of `func1.func2` then I see a compilation error.

```
func1.func2 = function(){};
```

**Error**

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

var func1.func2 = function(){};
```

What type was `func1` on first line 1 and what did it become on line 2.

```
var func1 = function(){};
func1.func2 = function(){};
```

Comment: `func1` is a [Function Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) and as such, can have properties dynamically assigned

Comment: When you do `var func1`, you are creating a new variable called `func1`.  `func1.func2` doesn't create a new variable, it adds a property to a variable that already exists.

Comment: If you add a `var` in front of it, then you're creating a variable and variable names can't have periods. That's why you get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function in JavaScript is an object too, that can have properties:

```
function func1(){} // a function object
console.log(func1.name); //=> "func1"
```

An anonymous function doesn't have a name but it's still a function object so:

> What type was func1 on first line 1 and what did it become on line 2.

Still a function, with a property `func2` containing another anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

One form of [variable statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2) is:

```
var identifier [optional assignment];
```

The identifier in a variable statement must meet the [rules for identifier names](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6), one of which is that they can't contain a "." character. So:

```
var func1 [...];
```

is OK but:

```
var func1.func2 [...];
```

is not. The interpreter stops at the identifier because it's a syntax error and that's it, it can't proceed with the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

`func1` is a function on **both** lines. You can confirm this using `typeof`:

```
var func1 = function(){};
typeof func1; // "function"
func1.func2 = function(){};
typeof func1; // "function"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func1.func2 = function(){};
```

If `func1` is not defined you are trying to access a property of `undefined` which causes an exception to be thrown.

```
var func1.func2 = function(){};
// SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

JavaScript syntax does not allow a dot to be inserted in a variable's name and therefore the interpreter returns a syntax error error.

```
var func1 = function(){};
func1.func2 = function(){};
```

A function in javaScript is a Function object, therefore, as all javascript objecta a method can be added dynamically to it at run-time. So `func1` is Function Object and `func2` is another function object. This is the correct way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Actually, if `func1` is not defined then you'd get a reference error. The "trying to access X of undefined" error usually happens when you are trying to access a non-existing property of an object. Because in that case, the return value is actually `undefined`.